# How to include a posting on Twitter with ASP Classic?

Tags: post, twitter, asp-classic

I need to create a system that one post news on my Twitter. I found this code on the web that looks like it does. I created a Twitter API, filled the ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecret.

I tested the code it is free of error, but not put on Twitter. Can anyone help me solve this?

This Code below is for this very reason?

```
<!--#include file="oauth/cLibOAuth.asp"-->
<%
Dim objOAuth : Set objOAuth = New cLibOAuth
objOAuth.ConsumerKey = twitter_consumer_key
objOAuth.ConsumerSecret = twitter_consumer_secret
objOAuth.EndPoint = "http://twitter.com/statuses/update.json"
objOAuth.Host = "api.twitter.com"
objOAuth.RequestMethod = "POST"
objOAuth.UserAgent = "Alert System Updater" 

objOAuth.Parameters.Add "oauth_token", twitter_oauth_token
objOAuth.Parameters.Add "oauth_token_secret", twitter_oauth_secret
objOAuth.Parameters.Add "status", tstatus
objOAuth.Send()

Dim strResponseText : strResponseText = objOAuth.ResponseText
Dim strErrorCode : strErrorCode = objOAuth.ErrorCode

If Not IsNull(strErrorCode) Then
Response.Status = RESPONSE_STATUS_500
Response.Write strErrorCode
Else
Response.ContentType = "text/html"
Response.CharSet = "utf-8"
Response.Write strResponseText
End If
%>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking

Comment: [Already asked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31710869/692942) did you search first?

Comment: @Lankymart: the other question doesn't have an answer, so even if she found it, it's not going to help her.

Comment: @Martha regardless it is the exact same issue, the other question has more detail and doesn't have any answers, so what makes you think this one will be different?

Comment: Also related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/15905921/692942. How many questions do we need?

Comment: @Lankymart: as many as it takes to get a useful answer, I expect. (Unfortunately, I know nothing whatsoever about posting to Twitter, so I can't help.)

Comment: Please show result of `Response.Write strResponseText`

Comment: Hi johnny, I have a news system in a website and I need to post this news on the site also post on my Twitter, that's what I need.

Comment: Lankymart Hi, yes I researched and found nothing that works, the closer to work I found was the post that you indicated, I found more posts Stack but none works, neither does what I need. In PHP there are several examples in ASP but there are very few.

Comment: Hi Zam, this is the test: http://www.jcrefeicoes.com.br/teste1-1.asp

Comment: Doesn't justify duplicating the question that is where me and @Martha disagree.

Comment: @Lankymart: clearly, the older questions aren't gathering answers. New posters don't have enough reputation to put bounties on existing questions. (Heck, they don't even have enough reputation to upvote a question.) Editing just to "bump" a question is frowned upon, so if they suggest such an edit, it's likely to be rejected. Thus, the **only** option available to a new user is to post a new question. It's kind of... disingenuous to scold them for employing the only option they have at their disposal, don't you think?

Comment: @Martha Neither question is a good question both OPs need to spend more time adding meat to their questions, maybe then they would get more votes. Its clear that duplicate questions are frowned upon, as for bumping questions by editing them, don't see a problem with this with one caveat - *The edit should be a substantal improvement to the question*